# Why I cannot apply .remove() method to list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Actual code:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
no_c_list = my_list.remove('c')
print(no_c_list)
```

The expected output is:

> ['a', 'b']

But in reality, I'm getting `None`:
[image]

**What I'm doing wrong and what should I do to remove the item from the list?**

Comment: Please print `my_list` which is the list from which you removed `'c'`. List `.remove()` works in-place.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors or textual program output when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste the result, formatted like multi-line code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`remove()` does not return anything. Or, perhaps to be more precise, it returns `None`. You're removing `'c'` from the my_list and then setting the no_c_list to `None`.

```py
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
my_list.remove('c')
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `.remove()` function incorrectly. The `remove()` function removes the element from the `my_list`, it doesn't create a new list that doesn't have the element. Try this

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
my_list.remove('c')
print(my_list)
```

https://repl.it/repls/ElementaryCourageousRadius